# Post data doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, browser

Here is my code:

```
<body onload="ccform.submit();">
<form id="ccform" name="ccform" method="post" action="https://www.XXXX.com" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="XXX" />
    .....

</form>
```

this works fine both on ie9 and chrome, but in the firefox, it stopped at the this page instead of posting to "https://www.XXXX.com".

then i changed the code to

```
<body>
<form id="ccform" name="ccform" method="post" action="https://www.XXXX.com" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="XXX" />
    .....

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.onload = ccform.submit();
</script>
```

it still worked on ie9 and chrome but not firefox. Does anyone know why? thanks

Comment: Firefox behavior looks sane to me. Auto-submitting a form on page load doesn't look right.

Comment: Also: your second version doesn't run on page load, it runs immediately, and tries to assign the return value of `submit()` as the load event...

Comment: @bfavaretto do you know how to do the form auto submit in firefox?

Comment: No, maybe but you should check the error console, maybe ff is issuing a js error (probably security-related)

Comment: By the way: I just tested your code in Firefox, and it works for me (FF 13.01, OSX 10.7.4).

Comment: Really? I am not sure why it happened on my computer, and there is any error in the error console as well, anyway, i used the $("ccform").submit(), that is easy actually. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with bfavaretto that it is strange to submit on page load.

If you want to submit when the document is ready, you can use jquery :

load jquery :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then post your form

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = jQuery("#ccform");
    form.submit(); 
}
</script>
```